# iOS friendly jQuery lightbox video player

Tags: jquery, ios, video, lightbox

I'm looking for a jQuery lightbox plugin that will be used to play a video. In the browser, clicking a thumbnail image of the video will open the lightbox modal and play the video, while tapping the thumbnail on a iOS device will bring up the standard iOS video player.

Do you know of one that can achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried **[orangebox](http://orangebox.davidpaulhamilton.net/)** ?

I bet that if you used youtube videos it would open up the ios youtube player.

Comment: Never heard of orangebox. I will check it out. Also, the videos won't be hosted on YouTube, they will be hosted with Brightcove.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at videojs.com. It supports iPhone/Pad. There seems to be a jquery Plugin. I havent testet that plugin so far, because I never needed. Just the video.js by it self works like a charm.